Using QPainter’s drawPixmap/drawImage to draw images, the images look blurry
I used QPainter’s drawPixmap() to draw an image, and the result is shown as B in the following picture.
Then, I opened the same image in the image viewer program provided by Windows, zooming it even smaller, as shown in A in the following picture.

It’s obvious that B is larger than A, but it is not as clear as A. B has noticeable Aliasing.
I tried setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing) and setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform),  it had some effect, but not enough to solve the problem.
I tried different ways to display the same image(OpenGL, webEngine, QPainter.drawPixmap, graphicsView), and the results varied, but all of them were of lower quality than the Windows built-in image viewer.

I don’t think it’s an issue with the image’s clarity. When I use drawPixmap() to draw the image and call QPainter’s scale() method to enlarge it, I can see the details of the image.
Does anyone know how to draw images in Qt with the same level of clarity as the built-in Windows software? Even when I scale down the image, I want to avoid Aliasing problem.
-- EDIT --
minimal reproducible demo:
// canvaswidget.h
#ifndef CANVASWIDGET_H
#define CANVASWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class CanvasWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CanvasWidget(QImage img, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void zoomIn();
    void zoomOut();

signals:

protected:
    QSize sizeHint();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override;

private:
    qreal scale;
    QPixmap pixmap;
};

#endif // CANVASWIDGET_H

// canvaswidget.cpp
#include "canvaswidget.h"
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>

CanvasWidget::CanvasWidget(QImage img, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, scale(1.0)
{
    // make sure high resolution source
    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img.scaled(img.size() * 10, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
}

void CanvasWidget::zoomIn() {
    scale = fmin(scale + 0.1, 10);
    update();
}

void CanvasWidget::zoomOut() {
    scale = fmax(scale - 0.1, 0.1);
    update();
}

void CanvasWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    if(!pixmap) {
        return QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    }
    QPainter p(this);

    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    p.drawPixmap(0,0,width() * scale,height() * scale, pixmap); // draw image
}

void CanvasWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{

    if(event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier) {
        QPointF delta = event->angleDelta();
        int v_delta = delta.y();
        if(v_delta > 0) {
            zoomIn();
        } else {
            zoomOut();
        }
        update();
        adjustSize();
    } else {
        QWidget::wheelEvent(event);
    }
}
QSize CanvasWidget::sizeHint()
{
    return QSize(800,800);
}


The left side of the following picture shows the result of this demo, while the right side shows the Windows built-in image viewer.

--- EDIT 2 ---
Here is the image I used in the demo, it's format was QImage::Format_ARGB32 and it's size is QSize(1541, 1188)  25KB PNG


Please provide a [mre].

@musicamante sure, This issue is more noticeable on low-resolution screens, like 1920*1080

Why do you scale up an image in the first place? What should this help except starting from a blurry image?

Scaling up the source image in the constructor is quite pointless (not to mention a complete waste of memory). If you want to start the canvas with a 10x size, then just initialize it with a 10 factor, or internally multiply the size by 10. It may also be relevant to know the size of the source image and its format (not just the file format, but also the image one, as listed in QImage::Format enums). If you can provide it, then add it to the post, but only as long as it's preserved: for instance, if it's a high resolution monochrome tiff, you may need to post it on some file sharing service.

OT: while there's no convention on terms, 1920x1080 may be commonly defined as "lower [than high]", "not high", "non High DPI", "[Full] HD", "standard", or "common" resolution, but it certainly is not "low resolution". Systems with such (and even lower) resolutions are still quite common. Currently, a "low resolution" term is reasonable for screens that are less than ~1000 pixel wide. This is also quite relevant when considering High DPI configurations, where the physical resolution does not match the logical one (eg: a 4k display that still uses a full HD resolution).

@chehrlic You are right, sir, it’s pointless.

@musicamante I uploaded the image I used in the demo, and it looks fine on the web.

I think I solved my problem, perhaps I overcomplicated the issue. I shouldn’t use p.drawPixmap(0,0,width() * scale,height() * scale, pixmap); to scale down the image, as it causes the image to lose details, I should use method p.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap.scaled(pixmap.size() * scale, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation)); instead.
Someone from Qt Forum inspired me and you all helps a lot, THANK U ALL

There are two causes for your problem:

the source image only contains black or white pixels, which is fundamentally like a monochrome bitmap (an aliased rendering of logic shapes) and is also based on lines that are only 1 pixel thick;
QPainter only uses bilinear sampling when smooth scaling, which produces artifacts when the scaling factor is smaller than 0.5 (downscaling by >2);

Scaling an aliased image like that will often create issues even with scaling factors closer to 1 (above or below), specifically with factors that are not based on powers of 2.
The simple bilinear interpolation will make those artifacts much more visible, because some of those "lines" (made of just one pixel) will be completely ignored with a downsampling factor greater than two.
There is no warning about this aspect in the documentation, but I've been able to track down a reliable source, from the words of Allan Sandfeld Jensen (currently Senior Manager and Principal Engineer of Qt WebEngine):

Likes like you are downscaling more than 2x. QPainter is doing bilinear
sampling when smooth scaling, and that produces bad results at 2x downscaling.
QImage::smoothScaled() uses a slower box scaling algorithm that works at even
the most aggressive downscaling.

Except for platforms/configurations that implement QPixmap transformations on their own, QPixmap indeed relies internally on QImage::smoothScaled() when using the Qt::SmoothTransformation mode.
This is achieved by using the "box scaling" written above, which is similar in concept, but uses larger "boxes" of near pixels of the source in order to compute the value of each scaled down pixel of the destination.
The attempt of using OpenGL didn't work because in that case using the SmoothPixmapTransform render hint on the painter is not sufficient (it is, indeed, a hint). The surface must also be properly configured so that it explicitly sets the number of samples per pixel used when multisampling (which is what is used to reduce aliasing); see all the answers to this related post.
The partial failing of QtWebEngine may depend on the default scaling algorithm set in Chromium (which also depends on the actual Chromium version in use in your Qt). Note that CSS provides the image-rendering property, which may improve that (I've not tested it with QtWebEngine, though).
The QGraphicsView approach will be identical in results, because its paint() function relies on the scaling done by drawPixmap().
As you already found out, the only appropriate solution for such images and scaling factors is to use QPixmap::scaled(), but be aware about the performance issues of the QImage conversion noted above: not only the QPixmap is converted to a QImage in order to be scaled, but it also has to be converted back to QPixmap in order to be rendered.
Those conversions are quite expansive, especially for large images.
Considering that, one may be tempted to just use QImage as a source, then only call drawImage() with a scaled() of the source QImage, but keep in mind that when QPainter is used on a QPixmap or QWidget drawImage() will always convert the QImage to a QPixmap anyway. That option may be an improvement, but it still is not optimal.
The more appropriate solution would be to actually scale the image at the required size but only when a resize happens; since you already get a QImage in the constructor, that's even better:

create a private QPixmap property, defaulting to null or an invalid QPixmap;
add a function that will write that property with the result of the source image scaled(), converted to a QPixmap;
override resizeEvent() and call the above function;
in paintEvent() check whether the cached QPixmap is valid (and call that function in case it isn't), then draw it;

Alternatively, invalidate the pixmap in the resizeEvent() and create a function getter for the scaled pixmap that will regenerate it if it's not valid.
Finally, as already noted in the comments, creating an upscaled image of the source in the constructor is completely inappropriate:

graphically speaking, there would be no real benefit in scaling again an upscaled version of the source image; on the contrary, it could theoretically result in further artifacts with some scale up/down factor combinations (possibly not with that 10x factor, since it's based on x2, but I'm not completely sure);
in terms of memory and computation, it's a huge waste of resources: remember that the fact that you have a compressed source image is irrelevant, the memory required by an image is always in its raw form (the pixel count multiplied by the color depth: for instance, your source requires about 7MB, but the 10x upscaled version takes almost 27); then, scaling a large image obviously requires more processing than scaling a smaller one, and you did that in each paintEvent() call, which is something that happens quite often;


What an insightful answer! It was a great help to me. I wasn’t actually familiar with QPainter.
THANK YOU

My problem has been solved in some sense,let me summarize, hoping it can help others who are stuck like I was.
I was planning to impelment a image viewer that supports zooming in and out of images. The method I used to zoom out is as follows:
CanvasWidget::CanvasWidget(QImage img, QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, scale(1.0)
{
    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
}

void CanvasWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawPixmap(0,0,width() * scale, height() * scale, pixmap);
    // ...
}

In this approach, the image became blurry when I zoom out. I tried several methods, such as:
•   Scaling the QPainter before drawing the image: painter.scale(scale, scale);
•   Displaying the image using QGraphicsView
•   Using QWebEngineView to display the image
In both QGraphicsView and QWebEngineView, the image resizes with the view. However, when the view is resized to a smaller size, the image still becomes blurry.
I even tried drawing the image as a texture in QOpenGLWidget but the image still appeared blurry when resized to a smaller size.
Finally, I relized that these methods unintentionally scaled down the image when resize it's container smaller, causing it to become blurry.

My implementation cannot be considered “wrong”, it just doesn’t meet my requirements.
Qt Doc says:

In some cases it can be more beneficial to draw the pixmap to a painter with a scale set rather than scaling the pixmap. This is the case when the painter is for instance based on OpenGL or when the scale factor changes rapidly.

If you want to maintain the quality of the image while zooming out, you should implement the following method as Christian saied.
p.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap.scaled(pixmap.size() * scale, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));


Note: what you mean with the "blurry" term is actually the opposite. The image scaled with QPainter actually misses pixels due to aliasing.
